# how could a non java/scala rest client discover akka/play rest cluster?

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, akka

I'm going to start up an akka/play cluster (I prefer play to spray because this is the default stack by typesafe and i prefer to stick to the typesafe stack).

In anyway, I understand akka nodes can discover each other by seeds, however how can a restful client (be it in java but not in actor technology) how can it discover the RESTFUL services provided by akka and play?

(its very nice that actors can auto auto discover each other by ActorRef but when I switch to rest how does that work?)

thanks

Comment: Why don't you register them in [zookeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ZooKeeper)? It has many clients for different languages and designed to be fault-tolerant.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me, but it sounds like you might be asking how to communicate with actors within an akka cluster from outside the cluster.  If that's the case, you might want to give the `ClusterClient` contrib a look: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/contrib/cluster-client.html

Comment: @cmbaxter but the `ClusterClient` does not talk aobut a REST client

Comment: @om-nom-nom i'm novice on this but it appears one of the strengths of akka cluster is that i don't need load balancers in front of it, and i don't need management servers for it (such as zookeeper) I wondered if that case is correct also when i expose my actors via REST

Comment: You have to roll the REST layer yourself.  There are a bunch of libraries to creates REST services so pick one.  But assuming the HTTP call ends up in some piece of your backend code, from there it's simple to lookup a clustered actor and send it a message.

Comment: @cmbaxter that means as soon as i use REST i loose all the benefits of akka cluster from client side prespective, it would not automatically allocate nodes as if it was an akka client, is that right?